# Extended jQuery spinnder throwing error when attempting to call method 'value'

Tags: jquery, widget, spinner

I require a spinner to overflow if a min/max value is reached, and I can do that as follows -

```
$('.inline-spinner').spinner({
    page: 10,
    spin: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.value > 99){
            $(this).spinner('value', 0);
            return false;
        } else if (ui.value < 0){
            $(this).spinner('value', 99);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

However, If I extend the spinner so that a `px` suffix is added to the input, the function attached to `spin` produces an error whenever I try to go beyond one of the boundary values (but works fine otherwise) -

> Cannot call methods on spinner prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'value'.

Can someone please tell me why this error is occuring, and how to fix it?

Here is how I'm extending the spinner (I also tried removing the `options` and instead included them in the `$('.inline-spinner').inlineSpinner();` call, but that also yielded an error) -

```
$.widget('ui.inlineSpinner', $.ui.spinner, {
    options: {
        page: 10,
        spin: function(event, ui){
            if(ui.value > 99){
                $(this).spinner("value", 0);
                return false;
            } else if (ui.value < 0){
                $(this).spinner("value", 99);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    _format: function(value) { return value + 'px'; },
    _parse: function(value) { return parseInt(value); }
});
$('.inline-spinner').inlineSpinner();
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally as I posted this question the answer dawned on me...

I'm extending `spinner` (and calling it `inlineSpinner`), yet I was calling the method 'value' on `spinner`. I changed the offending calls and everything is now working fine.

```
$.widget('ui.inlineSpinner', $.ui.spinner, {
    options: {
        page: 10,
        spin: function(event, ui){
            if(ui.value > 99){
                $(this).inlineSpinner("value", 0); // Changed this line
                return false;
            } else if (ui.value < 0){
                $(this).inlineSpinner("value", 99); // Changed this line
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
    _format: function(value) { return value + 'px'; },
    _parse: function(value) { return parseInt(value); }
});
$('.inline-spinner').inlineSpinner();
```